# Insert conditional breakpoint in Visual Studio as an atomic action (such that it cannot fire before the condition is set)

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2013, breakpoints

I have some running code and I would like to add a conditional breakpoint, but I only know how to add conditions to existing breakpoints. For example if I add a breakpoint to a line of my C# code, using for example `F9`, I can then right-click on the breakpoint's red dot in the left gutter which gives me this menu

[image: breakpoint context sensitive menu]

from which I can choose `Condition ...` to open up the conditional breakpoint settings

[image: editing a conditional breakpoint]

However I want to insert a conditional breakpoint in an often called function with a condition that is rarely true so that I can find out why an occasional error fires. I do not want to stop the code debugging, especially if it is an error that only manifests itself after some time. So the method above is inadequate. When I first insert the breakpoint, but before I have had a chance to add its condition, it will fire and the program will 'break'.

How do I add a breakpoint with an associated condition into code running under the debugger as a single atomic action, i.e. not add the breakpoint and then add a condition to it but add the breakpoint with its condition in one go?

Comment: Why does it matter that it breaks the first time (i.e. before you've had a chance to edit the condition)?  Just edit the condition, then hit F5 to resume debugging.

Comment: There are loads of timing dependent threads. Breaking, pausing, resuming affects the state of the relationships between the threads in ways that I do not want to happen.

Comment: I know commenting takes time and effort but it is super useful if people who down-vote a question leave some kind of explanation as to how the question might have been improved

Comment: Why not create the conditional breakpoint before you start running your code, then?

Comment: There, I counteracted the drive-by-downvoter with a +1 for you.

Comment: If I knew that there would be a problem that would be a great way forward. But if after running the code under the debugger for a few hours a bug crops up, and I suspect it is in a particular function under particular conditions why is it unreasonable to want to add a breakpoint to the running code in that function with the condition?

Comment: No, it's not unreasonable.  I agree that you should be able to do what you're asking, and I don't know of any way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *I do not want to stop the code debugging […].*
>   *When I first insert the breakpoint, but before I have had a chance to add its condition, it will fire and the program will 'break'.*

You can prevent this by making sure that the debugger isn't attached to the running process at that time:

1. **Detach the debugger** from your running process (via menu item *Debug* → *Detach all*).
2. Set a breakpoint.
3. Define a break condition on the breakpoint.
4. **Re-attach the debugger** to your running process (via menu item *Debug* → *Attach to process…*).

Comment: Excellent - of course! I'll miss a handful for diagnostic debug prints but I can live with that.

Comment: (There is one other possible solution where you would not even have to detach the debugger; namely importing a breakpoint from an XML document file. But I'm not sure how difficult it would be to write such a breakpoint XML document manually, and what would happen to your other breakpoints during the import.)

Comment: @dumbledad -- As I suggested in my answer, if you "break all", it should pause all threads where they are.  Seems a lot simple than this, and you won't lose your diagnostic debug prints.

Answer (score 2):

I work on [OzCode, a commercial extension to Visual Studio](http://www.oz-code.com) that has two ways of adding a Conditional Breakpoint in one click -

1. As QuickAction (similar to Alt+Enter in Resharper). This will suggest relevant conditions for your Conditional Breakpoint, based on the type of the variable (ie, `> 0` for numbers, `== null` for reference types, etc.
   [image: Add Conditional BP]
2. If you are already on a breakpoint and see the invalid value that is causing the bug, and want to add a Conditional Breakpoint on it so that you can return to the same point again after changing your code, you can add one from the DataTip:

[image: BP2]

This will automatically created a Conditional Breakpoint on the relevant value, which you can edit before you hit enter to approve:

[image: BP3]

Comment: Thanks Omer. Can I confirm that, since OzCode adds this feature, one shot conditional breakpoints are not possible in Visual Studio as-is?

Comment: @dumbledad To the best of my knowledge, no, they are not.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this in a multi-threaded scenario like you have, but what if you "break all" (using the little pause button or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Break</kbd>) and then set your conditional breakpoint?

Comment: The OP said, _"I do not want to stop the code debugging"_, so that is not likely to be an option…

Comment: @stakx -- If you follow the comments under the OP's question, you'll see why he doesn't want to stop the debugger: "There are loads of timing dependent threads. Breaking, pausing, resuming affects the state of the relationships between the threads in ways that I do not want to happen."  If you "break all", won't it pause all threads and thus preclude the OP's concerns?  I don't see why that isn't a viable solution.

Comment: Granted, you could be right. But since we don't really know what exactly _"there are loads of timing dependent threads"_ means, I tend to take the OP's explicit request (_"I don't want to stop the code"_) at face value.

Answer (score 0):

Tricky conditional breakpoints can be easily created programmatically.

```
bool someAwfullyRareCondition = true;

if (someAwfullyRareCondition)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
}
```

Comment: I'd have to stop the current debugging session to change the code, but I would like to know how to add a conditional breakpoint without stopping the running code.